# Override viewport property for lineto method in html5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, screen-orientation

I have used view port in my iPad app. Here it is:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;
```

And, I have written a code to draw lines on HTML5 canvas.

I am creating canvas as:

```
var mycanvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var context = canavas.getContext('2d');

..
```

It is working fine if canvas is created in portrait mode and lines are drawn in portrait mode too. But if we change the orientation, there is some gap between the mouse moved and line drawn on canvas. When i removed the viewport line from my html code, it is working fine but without using viewport everything looks bad. Everywhere it was suggested to use viewport in app.
Any way around.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks